# Combine server with local data using RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am using RestKit to download data from an API, namely an array of book descriptions. In my app, this data is read-only. I need that the user can mark some of the items downloaded as favourites.

I would like to save this bookmarks also in Core Data in a way that permits to use a NSPredicate to fetch only favourite books.

I can't just add a favourite field in the books entity because its value would be overwritten each time the app downloads data from server. I guess I need a different entity and I must establish a relationship between them but I couldn't find the right way.

How could I address this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your books must have an identifier property. Simply create a list of the identifiers of the favourite books. You probably don't even want to store this in Core Data. Instead, store it in an `NSArray` and store it in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Thanks Wain. To store favourites in NSUserDefaults is my current solution. I wondered if I could store that in Core Data to be able to create a NSPredicate that returns just the favourite books and not all.

Comment: You could yes. Storing it in Core Data should allow the predicate to deal with more favourites too.